# How to write a plugin to add users to a mail list

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, user-roles

I run a multi-site blog with about 300 sites.

I have an idea that I want to write a plugin that in order to add all administrators of blogs to a MailMan mail-list.  I just want administrators though, I don't want to add editors and subscribers to this email list.

I want to capture the event of being assigned an administrator of a blog.  Then I'll send an email to the subscribe email address of my mail list to automatically add the person.

So I was wondering which hook should I use ?   I think I want to send an email every time a person is set as an administrator.  I don't care if they are removed as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You would hook into `profile_update` and `user_register`.  First check to see if it's a new user and whether she is an admin/editor.

Then send the mail.  Same story with updating the user: see if the role has changed, and whether the new role is admin or editor.

```
<?php
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpse33949_profile_update' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse33949_profile_update' );
function wpse33949_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data = false )
{
    // get the updated user data
    $userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // whatever you need to send here
    $message = "Sign up for my email!";
    $subject = "Mailing List";

    if( ! $old_user_data && in_array( $userdata->user_role, array( 'editor', 'administrator' ) ) )
    {
        // we're inserting a new user...
        wp_mail( $userdata->user_email, $subject, $message );
    }
    elseif( in_array( $userdata->user_role, array( 'editor', 'administrator' ) ) && $userdata->user_role != $old_user_data->user_role )
    {
        // We're updating the role of an existing user, make sure they're 
        // becoming an admin or editor, then send the message.
        wp_mail( $userdata->user_email, $subject, $message );
    }
}
```

The above has not been tested.  Copy and paste with caution.  Just meant to get you started.